# Sqlalchemy with a pgpass file

Tags: postgresql, sqlalchemy, flask

Normally an SQLalchemy connection to postgres is something like this:

```
postgresql://scott:tiger@localhost/mydatabase
```

I was wondering how, ideally in flask, you could connect SQLalchemy to a file containing the password, such as the pgpass file.

Is such as thing possible?

Comment: `.pgpass` is used automatically by all programmes which link to `libpq`. If behind the scenes you application/framework/Postgres driver uses `libpq` you're set.

Comment: So I could just point it to the database without specifying the username or password as long as postgres knows where the password file is?

Comment: Postgres (the server) knows nothing about this file, your application/framework/Python driver for Postgres (e.g. psycopg) knows about it if it's build upon the [`libpq`  library](http://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/static/libpq.html).

Comment: Arrived here because I thought SQLALchemy was not looking at my `.pgpass`, but @MilenA.Radev's comment made me realize that the script I was looking at was actually preempting this by (incorrectly) providing `password=None`. Thanks!

Answer (score 7, accepted):

`.pgpass` files have records in the form:

```
host:port:database:user:password
```

If you knew you had exactly one entry in your `.pgpass` file, you could read in the values like this:

```python
from os.path import expanduser

with open(expanduser('~/.pgpass'), 'r') as f:
    host, port, database, user, password = f.read().split(':')

database_uri = 'postgresql://{}:{}@{}:{}/{}'.format(user, password, host, port, database)
```

Sometimes the database name might be listed as `*` (meaning all) in the file though and then you would have to specify the database explicitly. Also, if you have multiple records, you can read them all in using `f.readlines()` and select the one you need based on your personal criteria.

Answer (score 3):

In order for sqlalchemy to use a .pgpass file, it must be owned by the username of your application/framework and webserver.

And the .pgpass file must be only readable by that user (eg., chmod 600 .pgpass)

In our setup, that user is www-data, but www-data's home directory /var/www was not appropriate to put the .pgpass file in.

What worked for us was to:

1. create `/home/otheruser/.pgpass-www-data` with the required entry
2. run:

```bash
    $ chown www-data: /home/otheruser/.pgpass-www-data
    $ chmod 600 /home/otheruser/.pgpass-www-data
```

3. add to `/etc/apache2/envvars`

```
    export PGPASSFILE=/home/otheruser/.pgpass-www-data
```

4. update the app config.py to remove the password from SQLALCHEMY_DATABASE_URI
5. stop and start apache (not just restart)

And it worked!